# MongoDb query to get max of field inside array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to get the maximum of sections.Id in below document where collection._id = some parameter

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("571c5c87faf473f40fd0317c"),
    "name" : "test 1",
    "sections" : [ 
        {
             "Id" : 1,
             "name" : "first section"
        }, 
        {
            "Id" : 2,
            "name" : "section 2"
        }, 
        {
            "Id" : 3,
            "name" : "section 3"
        }
}
```

I have tried below

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id": ObjectId("571c5c87faf473f40fd0317c")
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$_id",
            "maxSectionId" : {"$max" : "$sections.Id"}
        }
    }
]);
```

But instead of returning max int single value it is returning an array of all Ids in sections array.

Further same query when executed in node.js it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your aggregation query need `$unwind`  for opennig to `"sections"` array

add your aggregation query this

```
{$unwind : "$sections"}
```

and your refactoring aggregation query like this

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[  
    {$unwind : "$sections"},
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id": ObjectId("571c5c87faf473f40fd0317c")
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$_id",
            "maxSectionId" : {"$max" : "$sections.Id"}
        }
    }
]);
```

and more knowledge for `$unwind`  : https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Answer (score 13):

You can do using simple [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage

Something like [**`this`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JbCopWi7tuF)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "maxSectionId": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$sections",
        {
          "$indexOfArray": [
            "$sections.Id",
            { "$max": "$sections.Id" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace $group with $project

`In the $group stage, if the expression resolves to an array, $max does not traverse the array and compares the array as a whole.`

`With a single expression as its operand, if the expression resolves to an array, $max traverses into the array to operate on the numerical elements of the array to return a single value`
[[sic]](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/)

Comment: using $project throws exception: invalid operator '$max', code 15999

Comment: what version of mongodb are you using... in that case use unwind as told by @kakashi hatake but use it after your match query to limit the number of unwinded documents

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7. I need max of all unwinded sections but of  particular collection._id for which filter is already applied, so can't apply filter on sections.Id.

Comment: i meant filter with object id first then unwind like this [{"$match": {"_id": ObjectId("571c5c87faf473f40fd0317c")}},{$unwind:"$sections"}], if you unwind first all the documents irrespective of objectId doc you want will be unwinded first